# Batch insert into related tables with auto-generated keys using prepared statements

Tags: sql, db2

I have two related tables(DB2 database) in my applications say A and B. A has an auto-generated primary key and this key is used as a foreign key in table B. My application has a business case where data has to be bulk inserted into tables A and B. The insert into B should have the auto-generated id of the corresponding insert into A as its id value.

A solution that I came up with is to query the next id value to be generated in table A and use it in the prepared statement of table B.

But my fear is any concurrent insert into table A when table B is being batch inserted would corrupt the consistency of data between these two tables.

Any help with the optimal approach would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not to do it the other way round - insert into a, get the id, insert into b, repeat?

Comment: Can but here i have to use batch inserts in both table A and B since the data is huge. If I have say 10k records in the dataset it is not optimal to run 3 queries for every record.

Comment: Absolutely normal. Did you try it? A good database would do it in less than a second.

Comment: No but this would definitely take a toll on performance

Comment: Or not. And you are now busying yourself with a problem that you have no solution for, to solve an imaginary performance issue. The worst way to pass time, if you ask me.

Comment: @meesun Can you be more specific about your batch inserts? Do you want to insert 1 row into both tables per each of 10k records of your dataset, which, let's say, contains data for both tables in the same record?

Comment: You don't need 3 queries, if you use SELECT ... FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO...). You only need 2 then as the first returns the ID.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein thats correct

Comment: @YourCommonSense The performance issue is not imaginary. Running 3(or 2 queries as mao mentioned) for every record is way heavier than running a single batch query for say 1000 records in my dataset. I have experiences where batching has significantly improved performance.

Comment: talk about premature optimization

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Consider the constants as parameters for the `A.A_VAL` & `B.B_VAL` columns. `A_ID` generated for `A` is used for `B.A_ID`.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE A (A_ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, A_VAL INT) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE B (B_ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, A_ID INT, B_VAL INT) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;

WITH 
  IA (A_ID, A_VAL) AS 
(
SELECT A_ID
, A_VAL -- Not needed. Just to show it in output
FROM NEW TABLE (INSERT INTO SESSION.A (A_VAL) VALUES (10))
)
, IB (B_ID, A_ID, B_VAL) AS
(
SELECT B_ID, A_ID, B_VAL -- All not needed. Just to show them in output. 
FROM NEW TABLE 
(
INSERT INTO SESSION.B (A_ID, B_VAL)
SELECT A_ID, 100 FROM IA
)
)
SELECT 
  IA.A_ID AS A_ID_A, IA.A_VAL
, IB.B_ID, IB.A_ID AS A_ID_B, IB.B_VAL  
FROM IA, IB
;
```

The outer `SELECT` may be any, if you don't want the values of inserted rows in the output. You may use just `SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` instead. The technique shown here is called `select from a data-change operation`.
The problem with such an approach is, that this statement can't be used in batches.
Another solution with such a statement would be to insert all the input rows to some temporary table first, and use a similar statement only once on whole dataset afterwards. But there is an additional requirement on the input dataset in this case. You must have an ability to join 1:1 the rows from it to itself using the columns of `A` only. For example, the input dataset is enumerated, and such a row numbering column is in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch inserts into both tables simultaneously

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_BATCH_A (A_ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, A_VAL INT) IN USERSPACE1;
CREATE TABLE TEST_BATCH_B (B_ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, A_ID INT, B_VAL INT) IN USERSPACE1;
```

You can try the following JDBC code with these tables, if you want to use batch inserts into both tables simultaneously.

```
String stmt = 
  "BEGIN ATOMIC "
+ "DECLARE L_RES INT; "

+ "FOR C1 AS "

+ "WITH "
+ "  IA (A_ID) AS "
+ "("
+ "SELECT A_ID "
+ "FROM NEW TABLE (INSERT INTO TEST_BATCH_A (A_VAL) VALUES (?)) "
+ ") "
+ ", IB (B_ID) AS "
+ "("
+ "SELECT B_ID "
+ "FROM NEW TABLE "
+ "("
+ "INSERT INTO TEST_BATCH_B (A_ID, B_VAL) "
+ "SELECT A_ID, CAST(? AS INT) FROM IA "
+ ")"
+ ")"
+ "SELECT 1 C1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WHERE 1=0 "

+ "DO SET L_RES=1; END FOR;"

+ "END";

CallableStatement pst = con.prepareCall(stmt);
pst.setInt(1, 1); pst.setInt(2, 100); pst.addBatch();
pst.setInt(1, 2); pst.setInt(2, 200); pst.addBatch();
pst.setInt(1, 3); pst.setInt(2, 300); pst.addBatch();
pst.executeBatch();
```